# Splitting strings in python in user defined manner

Tags: python

I have data in the following format:

Input Data:

```
#@ <id_1d3s2ia_p3m_zkjp59>
<Eckhard_Christian>     <hasGender>     <ma<>le> .
#@ <id_1jmz109_1gi_t71dyx>
<Peter_Pinn<>e>   <created>       <In_Your_Arms_(Love_song_from_"Neighbours")> .
#@ <id_v9bcjt_ice_fraki6>
<Blanchester,_Ohio>     <hasWebsite>    <http://www.blanchester.com/> .
#@ <id_10tunwc_p3m_zkjp59>
<Hub_(bassi~st)> <hasGender>     <ma??le> .
```

Output Data:

```
<Eckhard_Christian>     <hasGender>     <male> <id_1d3s2ia_p3m_zkjp59>.
<Peter_Pinne>   <created>       <In_Your_Arms_(Love_song_from_"Neighbours")> <id_1jmz109_1gi_t71dyx>.
<Blanchester,_Ohio>     <hasWebsite>    <http://www.blanchester.com/> <id_v9bcjt_ice_fraki6>.
<Hub_(bassist)> <hasGender>     <male> <id_10tunwc_p3m_zkjp59>.
```

That is in the output data I want to delete all other characters except: alphanumeric and `:`,`/`,`/`,`.`,`_`,`(`,`)` between any two starting and ending `<` `>`. I know python allows me to split using `string.split()` but if I split using `<` `>` as demarkers then for `<ma<>le>` I get `(<ma,<>,le>)`.

Is there some other way by which I may split in python so that I may get the data in the desired form. Also I want preceding lines `<` `>` (following `#` `@`) to appear as the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is always a whitespace character before/after the "proper" `<` and `>`, you could try something like this, using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

```
import re
with open('data') as data:
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('#@'):
            id_ = re.search('\s(<.*>)', line).group(1)
            fields = re.findall('(<.*?>)\s', next(data))
            fields = ['<' + re.sub(r'[^\w:/._()"]', '', f) + '>' for f in fields]
            print fields + [id_]
```

Output:

```
['<Eckhard_Christian>', '<hasGender>', '<male>', '<id_1d3s2ia_p3m_zkjp59>']
['<Peter_Pinne>', '<created>', '<In_Your_Arms_(Love_song_from_"Neighbours")>', '<id_1jmz109_1gi_t71dyx>']
['<Blanchester_Ohio>', '<hasWebsite>', '<http://www.blanchester.com/>', '<id_v9bcjt_ice_fraki6>']
['<Hub_(bassist)>', '<hasGender>', '<male>', '<id_10tunwc_p3m_zkjp59>']
```